# jQuery if/else view/hide layer

Tags: jquery, if-statement, width, visibility, adobe-edge

I'm making a responsive website slide bar in edge animate, and I've made 2 slides for 1 slide (So they can adjust responsibly). I want the second slide to show if the window width is below 786px and the first slide to show if it's above. This is the code I used:

```
var n = $(window).width();
if (n > 768) {
    // Show an Element.
    //  (sym.$("name") resolves an Edge Animate element name to a DOM
    //  element that can be used with jQuery)
    sym.$("#panel_01_photo").show();
    // Hide an Element.
    //  (sym.$("name") resolves an Edge Animate element name to a DOM
    //  element that can be used with jQuery)
    sym.$("#panel_02_photo").hide();
}
else {
    // Show an Element.
    //  (sym.$("name") resolves an Edge Animate element name to a DOM
    //  element that can be used with jQuery)
    sym.$("#panel_02_photo").show();
    // Hide an Element.
    //  (sym.$("name") resolves an Edge Animate element name to a DOM
    //  element that can be used with jQuery)
    sym.$("#panel_01_photo").hide();
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work. 
Thanks for anyone who helps.

Comment: Did you wrap that in a `$(window).on('resize', function() { ... });` ?

Comment: No, I tried now but I'm not sure if I did it right (I'm new to js and jquery):

`var n = $(window).width();
$(windows).on("resize", function(){
if ($(window).width() > 768) {

 sym.$("#panel_01_photo").show();


 sym.$("#panel_02_photo").hide();
}
else {
 
 sym.$("#panel_02_photo").show();
 
 sym.$("#panel_01_photo").hide();
}
});
`

Comment: You need to place the `var n = $(window).width()` inside the resize function for it to update, otherwise `n` will always be the width on first pageload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var n = $(window).width();
    sym.$("#panel_01_photo").toggle(n > 768);
    sym.$("#panel_02_photo").toggle(n < 768);
});
```

Comment: Do I need to hide the #panel_02_photo before this?

Comment: Well, sure does for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtXRZ/), you can just trigger the resize function to hide whatever is appropriate based on window size

Comment: Can it be that in Adobe Edge Animate it's different?